# AngularJS input form validation doesn't fire when it's model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get some form inputs to validate if/when their model updates.  Currently the only way to remove the pristine class is to manually type in the input box.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TgR7A/
In the fiddle if you click 'toggle' the 2 inputs (one is always hidden) populate with content via their models but the form input stays pristine.  I know this is AngularJS's way of handling form inputs but I'm hoping for a workaround (A.K.A hack!) that allows for the inputs to validate.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="toggleCtrl">
     <h1>{{ title }}</h1>

    <form novalidate class="css-form" name="swtichForm">
        <label>Input</label>
        <input type="text" name="one" class="one" ng-show="input_show=='one'" ng-model="one" required />
        <input type="text" name="two" class="two" ng-show="input_show=='two'" ng-model="two" required />
        <p ng-click="toggle()">Toggle</p>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.one {
border-color: blue;
}
.two {
    border-color: yellow;
}
.css-form input.ng-invalid {
    background-color: #FA787E;
}
.css-form input.ng-valid {
    background-color: #78FA89;
}
.css-form input.ng-pristine {
    background: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
function toggleCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Input toggle";
    $scope.input_show = "one";
    $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.one = 'hello';
        $scope.two = 'world';
        $scope.input_show = ($scope.input_show == 'one' ? 'two' : 'one');
    }
}
```

Comment: are you looking for some callback when a model is updated ?

Comment: What do you mean by model change? Change of value? In your code, you are actually rebinding the DOM and I am not sure what you want to achieve. Please specify.

Comment: Form validation is only for when the **user** changes the form through the form controls, not for when the backing data changes. Unfortunately.

Comment: I appreciate that stevuu and was hoping for a work around if possible

Comment: @sva I've updated the question so hopefully it makes more sense, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it's possible to use `$scope.formName.controlName.$setViewValue` (substitute `formName` and `controlName`) instead of setting it on the model. `$setViewValue` sets the view and model values and triggers validation. I'm entirely unsure though, and it would be a dirty thing to do in a controller!

Comment: In your demo, you are not changing models at all. and you are not populating the input box at all. What you did is toggle between to controls with all models untouched. Not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @sza clicking on toggle should place 'hello' in input #1 and 'world' in input #2.  Works fine for me anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find a good explanation [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838273/why-does-angular-js-form-pristine-not-change-with-direct-js-manipulation).

Unfortunately, althought there is a `$setPristine()` function, there is no `$setDirty()` one. As [stevuu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995639/angularjs-input-form-validation-doesnt-fire-when-its-model-changes#comment26312932_17995639) suggest, the least ugly way to solve your problem is to call `$setViewValue()` with the new value, and then force the view to update with `$render()`:

```
$scope.toggle = function () {        
    $scope.switchForm.one.$setViewValue('hello');
    $scope.switchForm.two.$setViewValue('world');

    $scope.switchForm.one.$render();
    $scope.switchForm.two.$render();

    $scope.input_show = ($scope.input_show == 'one' ? 'two' : 'one');
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJDpE/)</kbd>